# Multiple submit buttons with ajax & php not being processed

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm very new to PHP & AJAX. I have two submit buttons in HTML and I'm passing/extracting some values to/from a PHP file using ajax serialize() or say ajax. The problem is that serialize() is not able to distinguish which button is used, the "reject" button or the "accept" button which is creating problem for PHP file as it is neither processing for accept button nor for reject button.

At the end, my main purpose is to add some data to DB when a user hit**s Accept Button** & remove some data from DB if a user hits **Reject Button** But using Ajax.

HTML

```
<button class="p" type="submit" value="accept"></button>
<button class="p" type="submit" value="reject"></button>
```

PHP

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    if(isset($_POST["accept"]){
         // doSomething
    }else if(isset($_POST["reject"]){
         // doSomethingElse
    }
}
...
...
...
```

Ajax (It's not the complete code, just to have basic idea)

```
var form = $d('#formName');

$('.p').click(function(){

    var formData = $d(form).serialize();

    $d.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $d(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })

    .done(function(response){
        window.location.reload(true);
    })
});
```

Comment: You will need to give the `submit` a `name` attribute.

Comment: I added 'name="accept"' & 'name="reject"' to individual, but still the same. It does not process the PHP as above. @frz3993

Comment: this might dont work because you re sending bove input fields, try to put they in different form tags and then sending

Answer (score 0):

You will need to give your `submit` a `name` attribute. Example:

```
<button class="p" name="action" type="submit" value="accept"></button>
<button class="p" name="action" type="submit" value="reject"></button>
```

And your PHP code can check the `$_POST` value for action.Example:

```
if($_POST["action"] == 'accept'){
     // doSomething
}else if($_POST["action"] == 'reject'){
     // doSomethingElse
}
```

Comment: Did the same & my Ajax is as follow:

  '$d(form).submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // Serializing form data
  var formData = $d(form).serialize();

  // Submiting the form
  $d.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $d(form).attr('action'),
   data: formData
  })

  // Using .done method
  .done(function(response){
   window.location.reload(true);
  })
 }); '

Nothing better, only the page reloads due to '.done()' but PHP is not processed.

Comment: @KumarDeepak, see the other answer for how to add the submit parameter to the query string.

Answer (score 0):

Submit buttons are not serialized, you can get the data from them manually.
Also make sure the buttons have name attribute.

```
$('.p').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $(this).attr('name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value) + '&' + $d(form).serialize();

    $d.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $d(form).attr('action'),
        data: formData
    })

    .done(function(response){
        window.location.reload(true);
    });
});
```

Comment: thanx for replying back, I don't understand why? but `this.name` is giving some undefined variable error. Can you please help? @Musa

Comment: try `$(this).attr('name')` instead

Comment: Sorry, but now it says `unexpected token: name (encodeURIComponent)`
Please, help It's very important for me to solve it. @Musa

Comment: `var formData = $(this).attr('name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value) + '&' + $d(form).serialize();
     $d.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: $d(form).attr('action'),
         data: formData
     })
     .done(function(response){
         window.location.reload(true);
     })` JQUERY

PHP

`if(isset($_POST["action"]) == 'accept'){ // doThing 1}
else if(isset($_POST["action"]) == 'reject'){ // doThing 2}`

1st condition is execute in php N page refresh

Comment: @KumarDeepak try now

Comment: can you tell me what should I use in PHP `isset()` and in HTML buttons? I believe I am missing somrthing..

Comment: can you please explain me working of `var formData = $d(".p_type").attr('name') + '=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value) + '&' + $d(form).serialize();`, please...